# Change color of polylines on it's click in flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, polyline

I created a polyline in flutter using flutter polyline plugin. Now I want to change the color of the polyline when user taps on it. Please help me in achieving this.

Comment: yeah, you would have to rebuild a the polyline list and then pass it to a function `PolylineUpdates` the implementation file of the google-maps plugin. `import 'package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/src/types/polyLine_updates.dart'` hopefully this is the import statement, if not you would have to search the files. you can follow this link for help https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/PolylineUpdates-class.html

Comment: Happy to help!!!

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can change the `Polyline` color on tap:

First, you will need to define your `Polyline` object as a collection of key/value pairs using the `Map<>` [class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map-class.html), this will help you later on identifying which polyline is being clicked/tapped on, specially if you have many `Polyline` objects.

```
  Map<PolylineId, Polyline> _polylines = <PolylineId, Polyline>{};

  var pointArray; // var to hold the PolylineOverview
  int _polylineIdCounter = 1; // polylineId that you will use for your polylines
```

Then, you can set your polylines like this:

```
void _setPolyline() {
   pointArray = myPoints.decode(overviewPolylinePointsExample); // use PolyUtil(); to decode polylines

   final String polylineIdVal = 'marker_id_$_polylineIdCounter';
   _polylineIdCounter++;
   final PolylineId polylineId = PolylineId(polylineIdVal);

   final Polyline polyline = Polyline(
       polylineId: polylineId,
       consumeTapEvents: true, // Set to true to make polylines recognize tap events
       points: pointArray,
       color: Colors.red,
       onTap: () {
         _handlePolylineTap(polylineId); // function that will handle the color change and will be triggered when the polyline was tapped
    });

   setState(() {
     _polylines[polylineId] = polyline; // Add the polyline to your collection
   });
}
```

From the above code, `consumeTapEvents` is set to `true` to make polylines recognize tap events. Then, on the `onTap` method you will need a function that will handle the changing of color which should be like this:

```
_handlePolylineTap(PolylineId polylineId) {
    setState(() {
       final Polyline newPolyline =
            _polylines[polylineId].copyWith(colorParam: Colors.blue); // create a new polyline object which has a different color using the colorParam property
       _polylines[polylineId] = newPolyline; // add that new polyline object to the list
     });
}
```

Lastly, you can add your polyline list to the `GoogleMap()` widget like this:

```
GoogleMap(
    ...
    polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(_polylines.values),
    ...
),
```

Comment: How to do this for multiple routes? I am having list of multiple routes.